# Счетчик на картинке

Tags: php

Как создать счетчик, чтоб на картинке выводилось значение в зависимисти от даных в ссылке?

Нужно, чтоб считало год, месяц, день от указанной даты и количество непотраченных денег...

**Дополнено.**

Вот я задаю запрос

> `...counter.php?cig_per_day=40&grn_per_day=60&d=1&m=1&y=2010&cig=e-cig`

И оно на картинке мне пишет результат:

> Не курю 1 год 2 месяца и 3 дня.
> Не выкурено сигарет 100500 шт.
> Не потрачено денег 100500 грн.

Comment: а можно поподробнее расписать задачу? что за дата, какие деньги?

Comment: Сначала надо изучить GD, а дальше просто.

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Вот [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.image.php) всё, что Вам понадобиться!